# Windows: How to Specify Chunked Encoding Size?

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, chunked-encoding

I'm writing a Windows UWP program using `Windows.Web.Http` namespace. I stumbled upon a MSDN posting that mentions the below code will force chunked encoding. It does indeed do so. I've made some attempts at changing chunk size (http request) but the size is stuck at `0x10000`.

1. Is there a way to change the chunk size?
2. What is the rationale for making `GetInputStreamAt(0)` trigger chunking? Seems like a weird, not-documented-anywhere side-effect. Is there some logic to it?

Here's the MSDN posting:
[HttpStreamContent won't save stream](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0def8ef-e7a8-4b34-828b-bb4a2d5efa0f/httpstreamcontent-wont-save-stream?forum=w81prevwCsharp)

```
Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream contentStream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter dw = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(contentStream);
dw.WriteBytes(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
dw.StoreAsync().AsTask();
content = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent(contentStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));

content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

MSFT Guy [Says](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0def8ef-e7a8-4b34-828b-bb4a2d5efa0f/httpstreamcontent-wont-save-stream?forum=w81prevwCsharp#9fb98847-35cf-486f-9345-61ee75573912):

> ... the difference between the contentStream.Seek(0) and contentStream.GetInputStreamAt(0) is: using the first approach actually sends the Content-Length HTTP header followed by the entity body, whereas the second approach uses the Transfer-Encoding: chunked HTTP header, followed by the HTTP chunks. This is helpful in scenarios where the target server only accepts a "specific" format of the HTTP request.

Comment: Unfortunately at this time it is not possible.The `IInputStream.ReadAsync(IBuffer buffer, uint count, InputStreamOptions options)` only takes `Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead`.

Comment: I'm confused. How is IInputStream related to writing of chunked data?

Comment: I'm the OP. The program which uses chunked encoding, for request and responses, System.Net and Windows.Web, is part of the project at https://github.com/BSalita/Woundify/